# How can we use comparable for sorting with lambda expression in java 8?

Tags: java-8

In the Custom `class Student implements Comparable<Student>` class, if don't override `public int compareTo(Student o)` the method then it is giving compile-time error.
So my query is even comparable is a functional interface. Then why we are not able to achieve the functional programming in the case of comparable.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
    int rollno;
    String name;
    int age;

    Student(int rollno, String name, int age) {
        this.rollno = rollno;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [rollno=" + rollno + ", name=" + name + ", age=" + age + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student o) {
        return 0;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Student> al=new ArrayList<Student>();    
        al.add(new Student(101,"Vijay",23));    
        al.add(new Student(106,"Ajay",27));    
        al.add(new Student(105,"Jai",21)); 
        
        //Here I want to write my lambda expression using Comparable
    }
}
```

Comment: I think maybe you want interface [java.util.Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and not `Comparable`. Then you can sort `al` using method [sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) and use a lambda expression as the implementation of interface `Comparator`. Note that if you use method `sort` then class `Student` does **not** need to implement interface `Comparable`.

Comment: Using Comparator I have already done. But I wanted to use comparable as well using java 8. I tried a lot but unfortunately could find any approach.

Comment: Why you want to do that? the main reason behind Comparable interface to provide default (based on the property you compare in compareTo) sorting for your objects when used with sorted data structure like TreeSet, and Collections.sort, if you need to sort other than default property by Comparable than you can go for Comparator and you can used lamda also

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in Java Book Chapter 3 [144 page] ([https://www.amazon.com/dp/1119067901](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119067901))
[image]

Comment: So does that means we don't have any approach to implement using comparable!!!

Comment: You can do, but there is no meaning of doing this. If we have control over the particular class then we should always implement the Comparable interface. 

If you know, Comparator is an alternative to the Comparable interface, and We use the comparator only when we are using some library class or We want some custom sorting which is not satisfying our requirement by the Comparable interface

I hope its clear.

Comment: I know the difference between Comparator and Comparable and how to use both. But I want to see how to implement Comparable using java 8. Hope you get my concern. I just want to see how we can write lambda for Comparable.